# How to test if lazy loaded component is present using react testing library?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am using the 'react-lazyload' package to lazy load a component that renders images and I would like to write a test using react testing library that would check if the images are present when the user scrolls to the desired viewport.

I am using fireEvent to fire a scroll event so I can assert if my images are visible however the test fails. I'm still getting the hang of testing library so not sure where I am going wrong, any help would be appreciated.

//Lazyloaded component that is part of parent component

```
  ....
  <LazyLoad offset={950}>
    <ImageWrapper>
      <picture>
        <source type="image/webp" srcSet={heroImageWebp} />
        <source type="image/png" srcSet={heroImagePng} />
        <img src={heroImagePng} alt={'product-showcase'} />
      </picture>
      <AnimationWrapper>
        <MobileReaderAnimation
          animate={mobileReaderAnimationVisibility}
          initial={'hidden'}
          animations={animationsEnabled}
        />
      </AnimationWrapper>
    </ImageWrapper>
  </LazyLoad>
  ....
```

//test file

```
  it('should show images on scroll', async () => {
    renderComponent(defaultProps);
    console.log('window.scrollY', window.scrollY); //0

    fireEvent.scroll(window, { target: { scrollY: 1500 } });

    console.log('window.scrollY', window.scrollY);//1500

    expect(await screen.findByAltText('product-showcase')).toBeVisible();
  });
```

Comment: Did you try debugging what kind of DOM the `renderComponent(defaultProps);` renders in the test? https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/about/#screendebug

Comment: @Shota Yes, I would see an empty div where the images are meant to be but no images loading. I wasn't sure if I am simulating the scroll correctly, what do you think?

Comment: @Sai_91According to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/twobin/react-lazyload/issues/120) using [`forceVisible`](https://github.com/twobin/react-lazyload#forcevisible) seems to be the only workaround when using Jest.

Comment: @juliomalves Thanks for pointing me to that page. Although it's not ideally how I wanted to test it, it seems there is no workaround for it. Using forceVisible did make jest find the image. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

We can mock the `LazyLoad` component from react-lazyload library at the top of our test file so that the `LazyLoad` component behave just like a wrapper around our actual component that we need to test for.

```
jest.mock(
  'react-lazyload',
  () =>
    function LazyLoad({ children }) {
      return <>{children}</>
    }
)

test('component wrapped with Lazyload', () => {
  const { screen } = render(<YourComponent />)
  expect(screen.findByAltText('product-showcase')).toBeVisible();
})
```